# I Want to send email from cakephp 2.x in company domain email adress

Tags: php, email, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am not able to send mail.with below code:- if I remove $Email->config('gmail') than i am able to send email on id lke :- test@gmail.com but unable to send email on test@test-test@gmail.com

below is the code i have added in AppController:-

```
  function sendEmail($email, $subject, $body){
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
$Email = new CakeEmail();
    $send=$Email->config('gmail')->from(array('support@test-apps.com'=>'test Apps'))
         ->to($email)
         ->subject($subject)
                    ->emailFormat('html')
            ->send($body);
 if($send){
    return "sent";
  }else {
    return "error";
    }
} 

my email config is :- 

class EmailConfig {

    public $gmail = array(
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'username' => 'my@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'transport' => 'Smtp'
   );
   }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP Sending Email - LAMPP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348064/cakephp-sending-email-lampp)

Answer (score 1):

you didn't set the config also. try this

```
function sendEmail($to, $subject, $body){
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
$Email = new CakeEmail();
    $Email->config('gmail') // gmail, smtp or any config you have created in email config
          ->emailFormat('html')
          ->from('tesst@gmail.com')              
          ->to($to)
          ->subject($subject);

 if($Email->send($body)){
    return "sent";
 }else {
    return "error";
 }

class EmailConfig {
    public $smtp = array( 
            'transport' => 'Smtp',
            'from' => array('info@domain.co.uk' => 'Company Name'),
            'host' => 'company host',
            'port' => 25,
            'timeout' => 30,
            'username' => 'email',
            'password' => 'password',
            'client' => null,
            'log' => false,                
    );

//add other email config e.g. gmail

    public $gmail = array(
            'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'port' => 465,
            'username' => 'my@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'secret',
            'transport' => 'Smtp'
        );
}
```

**jut need to change $Email->config('smtp') to $Email->config('gmail')**

and load `App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');` on top of current controller or AppController

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I have found the issue. the emailid is test@test-test.com. If i remove the hifen(-) than it send the email.
do you know what changes I have to make to send the mail having domain email with spl. character.

Comment: this shouldn't be your problem. dashes are valid. try to put the email between double qutation

Comment: will you please tell me your email config settings. Below is the code of my email config file
class EmailConfig {

public $smtp= array(
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'timeout' => 30,
    'username' => 'my@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'secret',
    'transport' => 'Smtp'
);

Comment: if you want to set gamil make an other config name it gmail

Comment: if I set the email config file than it gives error for al email id :- 

CORE/Cake/Network/Email/SmtpTransport.php line 99 → CakeSocket->connect()
CORE/Cake/Network/Email/SmtpTransport.php line 59 → SmtpTransport->_connect()
CORE/Cake/Network/Email/CakeEmail.php line 1122 → SmtpTransport->send(CakeEmail)
APP/Controller/Component/CommonComponent.php line 26 → CakeEmail->send(string)
APP/Controller/UsersController.php line 342 → CommonComponent->sendEmail(string, string, string)
[internal function] → UsersController->resendmail(string)
CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php

Comment: please set the ->from(email only) not array - recheck my answer plz

Comment: I have tried ->from(email only) but still facing the same issue

Comment: Connection timed out
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
Stack Trace
    CORE/Cake/Network/Email/SmtpTransport.php line 99 → CakeSocket->connect()
    CORE/Cake/Network/Email/SmtpTransport.php line 59 → SmtpTransport->_connect()
    CORE/Cake/Network/Email/CakeEmail.php line 1122 → SmtpTransport->send(CakeEmail)
    APP/Controller/Component/CommonComponent.php line 28 → CakeEmail->send(string)
    APP/Controller/UsersController.php line 342 → CommonComponent->sendEmail(string, string, string)
    [internal function] → UsersController->resendmail(string)

Answer (score 1):

https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
```

> Using CakeEmail is similar to using EmailComponent. But instead of
>   using attributes, you use methods. Example:

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();
$Email->from(array('me@example.com' => 'My Site'));
$Email->to('you@example.com');
$Email->subject('About');
$Email->send('My message');
```